# NDVI calculation problem in QGIS

Tags: qgis, ndvi

I have a satellite image with 4 bands, R,G,B,NIR.

I have used the QGIS raster calculator to produce an NDVI - standard (NIR-R)/(NIR+R). I am expecting an output between 1 and 0, but the raster has the following range:

min: -3.40282e+38
max: 0.555598

What on earth am I doing wrong here? I am using data from two different suppliers and getting similar numbers, so it isn't to do with the source file.

I am using QGIS 3.26.1-Buenos Aires

Comment: Whats the value range of the input raster?

Comment: That min value is likely a no data value.